# C#, Winforms settings

Tags: c#, winforms

I had a question, how can I make customization for the application. I have several forms. When the application is launched for the first time, the configuration window appears, so that the user can configure for himself. As after this will be configured, the main window will appear. If in the same PC, and open the same application again, it opens only the main window, and the configuration window will no longer be used, until the very end. Until the application is removed from the PC.

Do not offer the configuration file bin. Only with ***Settings***

How to write it correctly in the Program.cs file, in the line Application.Run(....)

Answer (score 1):

In the `Program.cs` class check the properties and open the form you want:

```
if(Properties.Settings.Default.MysEtting == "MyDesiredValue")
    Application.Run(new Form1());
else
    Application.Run(new ConfigForm());
```